# get complete rows from database in servlet and pass them to jsp using bean class

Tags: jsp, servlets, jdbc, javabeans

I have one table in database in which some fields are there and having one bean class with some private fields , setter and getter method i am trying to retrieve the using jdbc concept and setting the string value on those method and after creating instance i am calling them in jsp page it is printing some address like this only in first column and remaining are empty com.emp.TimeDetailBean@19bd846 please anyone help me out here 
 here is my bean class...

```
private String intime;
private String outtime;
private String date;
private String eid;

public String getInTime() {
    return intime;
}

public void setInTime(String intime) {
    this.intime = intime;
}

public String getOutTime() {
    return outtime;
}

public void setOutTime(String outtime) {
    this.outtime = outtime;
}

public String getEid() {
    return eid;
}

public void setEid(String eid) {
    this.eid = eid;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}
```

and here is my sevlet code

```
public class TimeDetail1 extends HttpServlet {

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, java.io.IOException {

        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        String eid = (String) session.getAttribute("eid");
        int count = 0;
        Connection con = ConnectionManager.getConnection();
        try {
            Statement st = con.createStatement();

            String Query = "select date, intime, outtime, eid  from fulltime where eid='"
                    + eid + "'";

            List<TimeDetailBean> ee = new ArrayList<TimeDetailBean>();
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(Query);

            while (rs.next()) {
                TimeDetailBean e = new TimeDetailBean();
                e.setDate(rs.getString(1));
                e.setInTime(rs.getString(2));
                e.setOutTime(rs.getString(3));
                e.setEid(rs.getString(4));
                ee.add(e);
            }

            request.getSession().setAttribute("ee", ee);
            RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(
                    "/TimeDetail.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);

        } catch (Throwable theException) {
            System.out.println(theException);
        }
    }
}
```

and now jsp code is

```
<%if(session.getAttribute("eid")==null)
{
    String message ="please login first";
    request.setAttribute("message", message);
    request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
%>

<caption><h2>List of user timing</h2></caption>
<tr>
    <th>date</th>
    <th>intime</th>
    <th>outtime</th>
    <th>eid</th>
</tr>

<c:forEach items="${ee}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>${item}</a></td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me every time -

```
<logic:iterate name="ee" id="item">
  <td>${item.intime}</td>
  <td>${item.outtime}</td>
  <td>${item.date}</td>
  <td>${item.eid}</td>
</logic:iterate>
```

Or

```
 <c:forEach items="ee" var="item">
    <bean:write name="item" property="intime"/>
    <bean:write name="item" property="outime"/>
    <bean:write name="item" property="date"/>
    <bean:write name="item" property="eid"/>
 </c:forEach>
```

and remove `${ }` from `items=" "` in your code.

```
EDIT
```

In your bean file make

```
private Date date;
private Time intime, outtime;
// getter and setter methods
```

In your action class use

```
rs.getTime(1);
rs.getDate(2);
```

One more thing, use import java.sql.Date in your bean file because 
`rs.getDate()` returns a `java.sql.Date`, not a `java.util.Date`

Comment: both are not working when i am using first one it is returning some rows but empty and when using second then returning only heading of fields not even empty row .... so both are not working... sir review my full code may be some mistake is there...

Comment: @sourav78611 What are the data types of the fields in the database?

Comment: eid is varchar and date is date type, intime and outtime are time type and apart from that sir when i am using getEid like that in printing step inside for:each that time is printing but only one row last one so there is no iussue with datatype..

Comment: @sourav78611 Yes there is. Either you set the data type of them all as varchar in the DB or change the data type in your bean.

Comment: i cant set date as varchar you tell me what should i do to change the datatype in bean class my whole code is written above tell me..  what should i do..?

Comment: thanks sir for suggestion but its also same not working no error like previous i have changed accordingly whatever you told its not working and working with getDate like that way also same only printing last row ...

Comment: import java.sql.Time in bean file.

Comment: sir that i have already imported if i would have not imported into then it will show error but its not showing so thats fine..

Comment: no sir its not working at all... no solution till now...no one is telling proper one i got all comments just as fixed syntax nothing was logical how to do... am still trying to figure out the problem please anyone help me out here...

Comment: sir i am getting this message on console of eclipse id may be by reading it u can understand the probelm  "INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time."

Answer (score 0):

Try iterating the `for-each` loop like below to get the value from the individual fields ,

```
<c:forEach items="${ee}" var="item">
    <tr>
        <td>${item.date}</td>
        <td>${item.intime}</td>
        <td>${item.outtime}</td>
        <td>${item.eid}</td>
    </tr>
</c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Try printing your values , when you retrieve from the database . And check whether you have data for all fields

Comment: No , try using the variable name as i mentioned in my answer

Comment: sir i have given answer of my question above that is not working properly i have explained that whats the problem there and apart from that i can see fields value in database and the way you are telling in that it is showing some error on console    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TimeDetail.jsp at line 36 like this...

Comment: yes sir it is returning error i told you already in my previous comment  like this    org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /TimeDetail.jsp at line 36

33:           <c:forEach items="${ee}" var="item">  
34:             <tr>  
35:                 <td>${item.date}</a></td>  
36:                <td>${item.intime}</a></td>  
37:                 <td>${item.outtime}</a></td>  
38:                 <td>${item.eid}</a></td>  
39:             </tr>  


Stacktrace: